# Python, Selenium, chromedriver не работает на windows 7

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Всем привет. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Не работает скрипт автоматизации с chromedriver на windows 7. В коммандной строке после запуска скрипта никаких ошибок не выводится, просто запускается Хром с пустой страницей.

На федоре и дебиане 10 все работает, также тестил на windows 10, все было ок.

Answer (score 1):

После переустановки Windows скрипт стал запускаться нормально. Так и не смог понять, в чем дело.